# What could this expression in Excel mean

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas, excel-match

Using `INDEX` and `MATCH` for lookups and came across an expression someone used in the form of:

```
=INDEX(*range used*, MATCH(MIN(ABS(data!E2-lookup!$L$5:$L$105)),ABS(data!E2-lookup!$L$5:$L$105),0))
```

`lookup!$L$5:$L$105` is the value lookup table range. I know what its suppose to do but the `data!E2-lookup!$L$5:$L$105` part does not make sense. How does this work?

Comment: I don't understand the lookup-range in a calculation either. Was it an array function perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This formula works only as an array formula.

The `MATCH` part gets the position of that value in `lookup!$L$5:$L$105` which is nearest to the value in `data!E2`. The `INDEX` part then gets the corresponding value in `*range used*`. In words of the formula: It matches that value in the array of differences `ABS(data!E2-lookup!$L$5:$L$105)` which is the smallest of those differences.

Example:

[image]

Formula in `F2` is:

```
{=INDEX($A$2:$A$11,MATCH(MIN(ABS(E2-$B$2:$B$11)),ABS(E2-$B$2:$B$11),0))}
```

Note, this is an array formula. Input it into the cell without the curly brackets and finish it with [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter].

Comment: ahh! yes, i forgot about it being an array formula only. great answer still, thanks.